# Environment.GetCommandLineArgs not working under Main

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to get a specific argument when the my executable loads from the command line. I am using WinForms and when I use it in the Main method nothing happens. If I use it under the Form1 constructor it works, but the message box is hit twice. In the FormShown event it works as well but the form is displayed and if I use `me.Hide()` within the event the form appears for a few miliseconds. How should I use it?

```
 Public Sub New()
       ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        SettingsController.DeserializeXML()

        If Environment.GetCommandLineArgs.Length > 1 Then
            ' Loop and find each argument
            For Each arg In Environment.GetCommandLineArgs
                If arg.ToString = "start" Then  
                    Try
                        MessageBox.Show("started1")
                        Me.Hide()
                        Logging.Log("TaskScheduler Process started for backup")
                       'call the function here
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Logging.Log("Function: " & System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name & Environment.NewLine & _
                              "Description: " & ex.Message & Environment.NewLine)
                    End Try
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

**Edit**
My `Main()` that is under `Form1.vb`

```
Public Shared Sub Main()
      Console.WriteLine()
      '  Invoke this sample with an arbitrary set of command line arguments. 
      Dim arguments As String() = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
      MessageBox.show("GetCommandLineArgs: {0}", String.Join(", ", arguments))
   End Sub
```

Comment: you have a loop.  if there are 2 args, the message box will display twice

Comment: I suggest you put a breakpoint and step through your code to see what is happening.

Comment: As for the title, if you want help on using a Sub Main, you should show *that* code.

Comment: @Plutonix but it enters into the If-statement when only the argument equals the "start" value.

Comment: @Plutonix I have added the Main method

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use `Public Shared Sub Main(args() as string)` in order to get arguments?

Comment: @the_lotus But how can I put the break point if I start the exe from command prompt. The breakpoint cannot be hit

Comment: Sub Main() is set as the Startup Object?

Comment: @Capellan Under project properties I have Form1 as start up form.

Comment: If the form is a startup object, then Sub Main wont be used. *what* exactly are you trying to do?  Not show the form when certain args are on the commandline?

Comment: @Plutonix If the "start" argument is passed, I want to call a function without displaying the form at all.

Comment: You don't need to run it from command prompt. In your solution property, under debug you can add command line arguments when running from VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Form Load` is a bad place to put code when you dont want to use a form.  In **Project Properties -> Application**, set the StartUp object to `Sub Main`.  Create a `Module`  for the `Main`:

```
' Can get the command line as a param:
Public Sub Main(args As String())

    Application.EnableVisualStyles()

    If args(0) = "/foo" Then
        ' do something else without a form'
        ' App ends when this block runs out of code

    Else
        Application.Run(New frmMain())
    End If

End Sub
```

Notes:

- You can also get the command line from:

  `Dim myArgs As String() = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`

  But that method will include the App name/path as `myArg(0)`.
- Using `String.Join` on the return from `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` might not be needed, you can get it as a string from `Environment.CommandLine`.  It seems odd to join an array only to split it later.
- For debugging, you can enter a set of arguments under **Project Properties -> Debug**

Comment: I am facing an issue. I am trying to call an async function from the startup module. If I don't declare the Main as async (Of Task) I get warnings. If I do declare the Main as async, then I get the following: No accessible 'Main' method with an appropriate signature was found. Do you know any workarounds?

Comment: Sorry, not with so little information.  You should post a new question with the relevant details including *what* you are trying to do as well as *how* you are going about it.

Comment: I have figured it out. Basically within the Main I was trying to call an async functionl, I had to add ".Wait()" at the end. Answer was similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002507/how-can-i-call-async-go-method-in-for-example-main

Answer (score 0):

Try simply this code in the LOAD event:

```
Dim MyLine as string = Command()
MyLine = MyLine.trim
```