# How do I use a launch switch in my application?

Tags: vb.net

I have seen and used applications that are "all in one".  where just launching the application would be running application.exe, but when you launch the same application with a switch for example: application.exe /settings the settings page would be launched.

I do not have any code as I don't even know where to begin researching the hurdle.

I would like my program to launch a specific form (and maybe limit the user to THAT form) depending on the switch used.

FYI I was testing the new “Ask a Question Wizard” prototype, I didn't realise it was going to post an actual question.

Ah well I figured I'll leave it up, hopefully myself & others too, might learn something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs not working under Main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052014/environment-getcommandlineargs-not-working-under-main)

Answer (score 0):

if you can make change in this using the switch then your  requirement can be fulfilled easily...

```
static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new YourStartupfFormHere());
    }
```