# Error message "CS5001 Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point"

Tags: c#, console, visual-studio-2017, console-application, .net-core-2.0

Unable to execute the following code
error CS5001    Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

What does this error message mean?

```
class Program
{
    static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        Account.accountTest accountTest = new Account.accountTest();

        bool result = await accountTest.CreateAccountAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the same error message because I had `async void Main` instead of `async Task Main`

Comment: @EldritchConundrum - `async Task` was the answer to my issue. Thanks. You should add it as an answer if people are already on C# version >= 7.1

Answer (score 193, accepted):

It means that you don't have a suitable entry point for your application at the moment.

That code will *nearly* work with C# 7.1, but you do need to explicitly enable C# 7.1 in your project file:

```xml
<LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>
```

or more generally:

```xml
<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
```

You also need to rename `MainAsync` to `Main`. So for example:

Program.cs:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

ConsoleApp.csproj:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

... builds and runs fine.

Comment: added <langversion>latest</langversion> to myproject.csproj still getting the same error.

Comment: @001: See my edited answer - the LangVersion needs capital L and V, and you need to rename the method as well.

Comment: @Pascal: We need far more information than that to help you. Which exact version of the C# compiler (that's the important bit) are you using? What's the context?

Comment: and that was the problem. After I found the Advanced button I saw its set to latest major version(default) which should mean 7.0. I set it directly to 7.2 c# compiler. Then it works :-)

Comment: What is the default LangVersion when left unspecified?

Comment: @StevenLiekens The latest major version - so 7.0 at the moment.

Comment: This was it for me. Language versions can also be set in the Properties page > Build Tab > Advanced

Comment: @JonSkeet This works fine while building the code, but I get same error while trying to publish the app. Any workaround?

Comment: @gauravthakur: It's very hard to tell without any more information about what kind of project you're working with etc. I suggest you ask a new question with precise details.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet for your reply :). It was silly mistake on side. I had only change Language version for Debug build and Publish uses Release build.

Comment: I lost about 30 minutes before I realized that the release configuration needed the same tweak that got my Debug version compiling. :-)

Comment: For those still with errors with language set correctly: make sure your Main signature is correct, with Task as a return type instead of void. If, like me, you only add "async" keyword the signature is not valid.

Comment: how about for aspnetcore console application project. there is no where to define the version.

Comment: @user2748728: I don't know exactly what you mean by "aspnetcore console application"  but if you've got a project file, that's where you put the version. (And I haven't seen anything in .NET Core that *doesn't* have a project file.)

Comment: Cannot believe after all these years this is still the ONLY solution. And BTW, <LangVersion> is not even in VS2017 intellisense!

Comment: @Fandango68: With the latest versions of the .NET Core SDK (now that C# 8 has shipped) you don't need to specify the language version - at least not in VS2019.

Comment: Oddly for me, choosing Latest Version did not work.  I ended up setting it to the latest version by selecting it from the dropdown in the Advanced page.  Makes no sense, but maybe worth a try if you're stuck.

Comment: Changing Main's return type from void to Task is the piece I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a stupid answer, but if your intend was to make a `Class Library` project, make sure you have not created a `Console Application` project by mistake.

I know of at least one person who's done it.

Comment: I was helping a team member work on an MVC project and this was the problem. MVC projects need to have their `Output type` set to `Class Library`. I am guessing it had been changed to `Console Application` inadvertently.

Comment: Found another person ...thanks for sharing....saved me time and some embarassment