# Code stops when using HttpContent.ReadAsAsync

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am trying to read async from HttpContent but my code exists on this method. It used to work but I recently had to switch to a console app because I wanted to make a discord bot. Does anyone know why the code "stops" when I use this in a console app?

I've tried using an async Main as suggested but it does not work

I am using this code:

```
public class BazaarInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("products")]
    public List<BazaarProduct> Products { get; set; }
    public static async Task<BazaarInfo> BuildAsync()
    {
        string url = "https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar";

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await ApiHelper.GetApiClient("application/json").GetAsync(url))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                BazaarInfo output = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<BazaarInfo>(); //Stops

                return output;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I call it from here:

```
public class Bazaar
{
    public Dictionary<string, BazaarProduct> Products { get; set; }

    public static async Task<Bazaar> BuildAsync()
    {
        var output = new Bazaar();

        var bazaarInfo = await BazaarInfo.BuildAsync();
        output.Products = bazaarInfo.Products.ToDictionary(product => product.Name);

        return output;
    }
}
```

And this:

```
 [Command("bazaar")]
    public async Task BuildBzItem ([Remainder]string id)
    {
        var bazaar = await Bazaar.BuildAsync();

        string sellSummary = "";
        foreach (var summary in bazaar.Products[id].SellSummary)
            sellSummary += summary.Amount + summary.Price;

        var builder = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
        {

            Description = sellSummary
        };

        await ReplyAsync("", false, builder.Build());
        
    }
```

And then here with a discord chat event:

```
    private async Task HandleCommandAsync(SocketMessage arg)
    {
        var message = arg as SocketUserMessage;
        var context = new SocketCommandContext(Client, message);

        if (message.Author.IsBot) return;

        int argPos = 0;
        if(message.HasStringPrefix("!", ref argPos))
        {
            var result = await Commands.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos, Services);
            if (!result.IsSuccess) Console.Write(result.ErrorReason);
        }
    }
```

And this event is assigned here:

```
    public static async Task Main(string[] args) => await new Program().RunBotAsync();

    private DiscordSocketClient Client { get; set; }
    private CommandService Commands { get; set; }
    private IServiceProvider Services { get; set; }

    public async Task RunBotAsync()
    {
        Client = new DiscordSocketClient();
        Commands = new CommandService();
        Services = new ServiceCollection().AddSingleton(Client).AddSingleton(Commands).BuildServiceProvider();

        string token = "ODQ1MzE1OTY2OTcxODA1NzI3.YKfL1w.SPXi_0xXbbrMziZ9JWiqHFX4dto";

        Client.Log += ClientLog;

        await RegisterCommandsAsync();

        await Client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);

        await Client.StartAsync();

        await Task.Delay(-1);
    }

    private Task ClientLog(LogMessage arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arg);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task RegisterCommandsAsync()
    {
        Client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync;
        await Commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), Services);
    }
```

Comment: How do you call BuildAsync? Why do you assign `response.Content` to a variable and then not use it?

Comment: You're probably calling `BuildAsync()` (directly or indirectly) from a non-async method somewhere up the chain. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Try making your `Main` method async (it should be working since [C# 7.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main)) and awaiting in it.

Comment: [Example of async `Main`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13003483/3181933) (as per Guru Stron's comment).

Comment: My main method cannot be async, it gives compiler error 'Program does not contain a static Main method suitable for an entry point'

Comment: I'm always suspicious when someone takes an ordinary word and puts it in quotes, like it is supposed to have some special meaning that we're supposed to somehow know. Why do you put "stops" in quotes? Can you maybe describe the exact symptoms instead (e.g. you need the debugger halt with a line of code highlighted, or the program outputs an error message, or the process disappears, etc.)

Comment: @JuanMingLao See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47588563/2501279)

Comment: What do you mean by "the code stops"? Do you mean that the program deadlocks, that the program terminates, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried using an async Main as suggested but it does not work

If you can't use `async Main`, then block in the `Main` method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().RunBotAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```