# 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am trying to implement the example provided in the Microsoft website, getting below error can anyone please help me with this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth#register-your-application

I am trying to implement sample code provided in App-only authentication, I am using VS 2016 console application.

```
static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Using Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.22.0
            var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appId"])
                .WithClientSecret(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"])
                .WithTenantId(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"])
                .Build();
```

Error :-

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS5001  Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Please let me know how to resolve the error.

Regards,
Ramesh.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message "CS5001 Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47588531/error-message-cs5001-program-does-not-contain-a-static-main-method-suitable-f)

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest using a [REST API gateway](https://docs.aurinko.io/unified-mailbox-api/email-api) instead of EWS directly, your job may be easier. Here is [the authorization flow](https://docs.aurinko.io/authentication/authentication-flow) then.

Comment: Thankyou Alexey as per requirement we are not allowed to use RES API :(