# Is asynchronous programming like a zombie virus?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am experimenting with asynchronous programming in C#, mostly trying to send API calls to an API I created, but from what I understand, it is only possible to call an `async` method drom another `async` method. However, my **Main** method cannot be asynchronous. I don't want to have to call the method synchronously using the `.Result` attribute because that ruins the point of asynchronous programming. Do I have to call the method from another thread or is there another solution?

Comment: What type of Project is it and what framework and version?

Comment: "my Main method cannot be asynchronous" - in language level 7.1+ it can be.

Comment: @Rup yep, only if he cant make it async by his own reasons

Comment: This is probably what you want: [How can I call an sync method in main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002507/how-can-i-call-an-async-method-in-main). Yes, you'll have to run one synchronously or wait for it to complete, to define the lifetime of your process. That one async step can call other code asynchronously though.

Comment: Main can be marked async but that just correctly implements GetAwaiter().GetResult() behind the scenes so it still blocks. That's just the way it is, and its fine. There is no synchronization context in console apps.

Comment: @Mateech We still need to figure out if OP only _thinks_ he can't or if he _actually_ can't.

Comment: I use .NET framework 4.7.1 and its a windows forms project

Comment: You shouldn't need to run any async code from Main in a winforms app.

Comment: There are many excellent reasons for using async/await especially in high load applications as it frees the main CPU from blocking threads whilst waiting for I/O to complete.  Those benefits must be weighed against using (slightly) more complicated programming techniques and it's not always the best approach.  If you do decide to go for the full async/await experience, then, yes, you need to use it 'everywhere'.  Using .Result is almost always a no no, and things like EF aren't happy either.

Comment: WinForms ... then this may be interesting for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types especially this section: [Tasks and the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types#tasks-and-the-event-based-asynchronous-pattern-eap)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Main can now be asynchronous:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args) 
{
   //TODO: do something more interesting
   await Task.Delay(100);
}
```

But even when it could not be, you could take advantage of asynchronous programming just with a little boilerplate code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

private static async Task MainAsync(string[] args) 
{
  // TODO: do something more interesting.
  await Task.Delay(100);
}
```

Please read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main) for more information