# Why do I get "The response ended prematurely" when using the HttpClient in C#?

Tags: c#, http, .net-core, httpclient

My first code of HTTP Client in .Net Core.
The server is running on my PC as well, so I want to send it to localhost.

I've added printing of the inner exception after someone recommended it here but it's not enough for me to understand the problem.

```
namespace HTTPClient
{
    // The object I want to send
    public class Msg
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Data { get; set; }
        public int RSSIR { get; set; }
        public int RSSIT { get; set; }
        public int Slot { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static Msg msg = new Msg
        {
            ID = "00CC",
            Data = "9F4CC",
            RSSIR = 123, 
            RSSIT = 321,
            Slot = 1
        };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://127.0.0.1:5001";
            Console.WriteLine("result = " , callURL(url)); 
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        public static bool callURL(string url)
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            bool Result = false;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            try
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                response = client.PostAsync("", content).Result;
            }
            catch (AggregateException err)
            {
                foreach (var errInner in err.InnerExceptions)
                {   // for printing the inner execption
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
                    Console.WriteLine(errInner); 
                }
            }


            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Result = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Result = false;
            }
            return Result;
        }
        
    }

}
```

The error I received from the loop inside the catch is:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely.
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
```

How can I figure out why can't I send a message to the server?
Does the content of the message can disrupt the connection generation?

I checked the server with another client and it's working so the problem has to be in my code.

EDIT:
The server is using https so I changed my URL to https as well and this is the error I received:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__65_1(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
```

Do I need to add some SSL commands in order to make a secure connection?

Edit2:
The new error after adding a command in callURL()

```
---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ThrowIfExceptional()
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__65_1(IAsyncResult iar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
```

Comment: Do `catch (Exception err)` and then `Console.WriteLine(err.ToString());` - what is the full exception details?

Comment: `HttpClient` uses async IO - so you should be using `async` methods with `await`. You should not use `.Result` because that can cause deadlocks.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary
The err value is:
msg: One or more errors occurred. (An error occurred while sending the request.)
source: System.Private.CoreLib
trace:    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at HTTPClient.Program.callURL(String url) in C:\source\HTTPClient\HTTPClient\Program.cs:line 84

Comment: Is http://127.0.0.1:5001 100% correct? Is the server running? Your code works so whatever it is, it's the server side

Comment: @Dai
which method should be with async? the only method is PostAsync

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary 
I just saw the server is using https and I used HTTP so I changed the HTTP to https and I received a new error (In the post)

Comment: @RoyAncri "async is viral", see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61656229/is-asynchronous-programming-like-a-zombie-virus

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, unfortunately, no, but I've received a different error:

in the post

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Yes, maybe it's not enough and I need to add something?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely` means the server to which you're making an HTTP request closed the connection without having sent back a complete response.

It has *nothing* to do with your client code, as it looks to compile & send content correctly.

Yes, you should be using `await client.PostAsync` but that *isn't related at all* to your question.

**Double-check that `http://127.0.0.1:5001` is 100% correct - maybe it's `https://` or not on port `5001`.**

---

If it is an endpoint using HTTPS, you may get `System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.` as it looks like you're calling a local endpoint.

.NET does SSL certificate validation by default & will throw an exception if you are trying to call an HTTPS endpoint for which you have no/invalid SSL certificate. You probably have not set up the localhost certificate correctly on your machine.

For now, you can bypass the check by setting [`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback?view=net-5.0) to always return `true` using [`HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.dangerousacceptanyservercertificatevalidator?view=net-5.0)

Initialise your `HttpClient` like below:

```
public static bool callURL(string url)
{
  bool Result = false;

  var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
  
  #if DEBUG
  httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
  #endif

  HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
  ...
}
```

---

However, please do note allowing all SSL certificates **is a security risk if used on anything other than your local dev environment**.

Read: [The most dangerous code in the world: validating SSL certificates in non-browser software](http://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Edabo/pubs/abstracts/ssl-client-bugs.html) by Stanford University

Comment: Now it is working. Very strange..
Thank you very much!

Comment: @RoyAncri Don't skip certification validation in production however for development, it'll be fine. Installing the correct SSL certificate on the production server will allow you to remove the above code which is a security risk if left like that on anything other than dev builds- hope that helps!

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Yes I'll read how to do it for the production project. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when porting a .net framework project to .net core. I managed to solve it by using WinHttpHandler like this:

```
var handler = new WinHttpHandler();
handler.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
handler.TcpKeepAliveEnabled = true;

using (var hc = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    return wc.GetStringAsync(new Uri(apiUrl)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If these solutions doesn't work for you, try this instead.
There may be particular instances where your function gets triggered but the orchestrator dosent get triggred and also some instances where an exception will be thrown saying "the local machine actively refused to connect to port 7071".
The primary reason for this is your TaskHub durable functions creats a local TaskHub in your Local Storage Emulator to run these functions. It is entirely dependent on your local machine and if this is corrupted in some way. It may cause various problems like the above-mentioned. Most of the time restarting your entire machine will solve your problem by clearing your LocalStorageEmulator and creating a new TaskHub.If this doesn't work then downloads an extension in VS Code called "Durable Functions Monitor".

Extenstion Id  :DurableFunctionsMonitor.durablefunctionsmonitor
Name: Durable Functions Monitor
Id: DurableFunctionsMonitor.durablefunctionsmonitor
Description: Monitoring/debugging UI tool for Azure Durable Functions
Version: 6.2.0
Publisher: DurableFunctionsMonitor
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DurableFunctionsMonitor.durablefunctionsmonitor

and once installed under the LocalStorageEmulator there would be some TaskHubs remove all those TaskHubs and restart your Visual Studio .This will solve your problem.