# System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsync(request) stops after 30 sec for a POST method inside a docker container

Tags: c#, docker, containers

A straightforward question, yet one that currently eludes me an answer.
I'm attempting to make a request to my API from a basic console application, and the request takes more than 30 seconds to complete. Interestingly, when I execute the application in a Windows environment, everything works fine. However, when I run it inside a container using Docker Desktop, the POST request consistently stops after 30 seconds. I suspect there may be a timeout configuration issue within my Docker setup. This behavior persists even when deploying the application in OpenShift. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, {URL});

var content = new StringContent({requestBody}, null, "application/json");
request.Content = content;

var response = await client.SendAsync(request); // it crashes here
```

**HttpRequestException:**

```
{System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely.
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
at RestSharp.RestClient.ExecuteRequestAsync(RestRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)}
```

I tried to change some docker settings to increase the timeout and be sure that it's not a proxy issue :-)

Comment: The error says the *response* sent from the server ended prematurely. Are you sure the server didn't crash or timeout in the middle of the response? Did you check the server's logs?

Comment: Which .NET version are you using? You can log HttpClient requests and responses at a low level [in various ways](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-6/#tracing) but .NET 7 and .NET 8 have made standard-based OpenTelemetry tracing almost automatic.

Comment: Try creating a small project using [.NET Aspire](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/get-started/build-your-first-aspire-app?tabs=visual-studio) simply to see what HttpClient and the rest of the application are doing, both inside and outside a container. Aspire configures OTEL in the template *and* includes [a dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/get-started/build-your-first-aspire-app?tabs=visual-studio#explore-the-net-aspire-dashboard) that shows traces and metrics.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you, I will do and let you know ;-)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I just used .net Aspire which I found useful to monitor distributed apps... What I did is to call my request api (configuring the resilience) from the template web-front and it works BUT it still running under windows environment. I didn't found the way to execute it inside a docker container to have my same behaviour issue..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was related to my proxy, which was blocking the response. By adding my API URL to the environment variable in the Dockerfile I bypassed the proxy and the problem was solved.
`ENV no_proxy="{api.domain.name}"`... You can use leading point and set subdomain. The solution was straightforward once identified, despite the complex search process.

Answer (score 0):

***If the you assuming it is because of `HttpClient()` timeout:***

The issue might be related to the default timeout settings of the HttpClient class in .NET, rather than Docker settings. By default, the HttpClient class has a timeout of `100 seconds` for both the entire request and reading the response stream.

To increase the timeout for your HttpClient requests, you can set the Timeout property of the HttpClient instance

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5); // Set timeout to 5 minutes (adjust as needed)
```

Additionally, you can also consider configuring Docker to increase its network-related timeouts, but since the issue is related to the HttpClient in your application, adjusting the timeout within your code should suffice

Ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=net-8.0

***If not:***

- Check for Server Logs
- Test your API with tool like `cURL` or `Postman` to manually make requests to the API endpoint that your console application is trying to access. This can help determine if the issue is specific to the console application or if it also occurs with other `HTTP clients`
- Inspect Network Traffic
- Review Server Configuration

Comment: Why make this assumption? The exception says nothing about a timeout, it says the *server* response ended prematurely.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Thanks. Yes, the exception message indeed indicates that the server response ended prematurely, which suggests that the issue might be related to the server rather than a timeout. Will update it.

Comment: @Jeevanebi Thank you for your answer. I forgot in my code to mention that I tried the InfiniteTimeSpan and same issue :

var client = new HttpClient { Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan };

Comment: @Jeevanebi for me it's not a client issue because it works great with other client like Postman, swagger... Network traffic is also ok. I think that it's definitely a server config issue, but what ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69513783/why-do-i-get-the-response-ended-prematurely-when-using-the-httpclient-in-c#:~:text=IOException%3A%20The%20response%20ended%20prematurely%20means%20the%20server%20to%20which,to%20compile%20%26%20send%20content%20correctly.

Comment: @Jeevanebi Indeed, I had already seen this article and tried the suggestions, but they were not relevant in my case.